# PHPMailer sends emails but the client does not receive them

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem in PHPMailer in particular. I have a contact form, and use PHPMailer to send emails. Apparently I can send, for me it returns "true", but the email does not arrive in your inbox. I've tried several ways to find the error, but without success. I tried enabling and disabling the SMTP with and without SMTP authentication, multiple forms. Follow my code below.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mysite.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
$mail->Username = 'my@email.com';
$mail->Password = 'passhere';

$mail->From = "Newsletter";
$mail->Subject = "Newsletter";
$email = $_POST['email_news'];
$mail->AddAddress('my@email.com');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$mail->Body = "
    <html>
        <body>
        <b>Email:</b> $email<br/><br/>
        </body>
    </html>             
";

if(!$email){
    $result = "error";
}else{
    $send = $mail->Send();
    if($send){
        $result = "sucess";
    }else{
        $result = "error";
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

header("Location: http://www.mysite.com");

?>
```

---

I managed to solve my problem using authentication via gmail. Was as follows authentication:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'my@email.com';
$mail->Password = 'passhere';
```

But I have a doubt. This authentication code is just for sending emails from gmail? Or is it an endorsement gmail provides for general validation email in PHPMailer?

Comment: Please check in your spam mail...

Comment: You do not echo `$result` - you are sure, that mail is sent? And did you check your spam mail folder?

Comment: I assume you've made them check their spam filters? Its possible that its being stopped at the other end?

Comment: Yes, the messages are being sent, it returns "true". The inbox is without spam filters for testing, and still not get. I use the same configuration on another site and it works normally, do not understand what might be happening.

Comment: How can you be sure it returns true? $result should be "sucess", but $result is never print out. Is $result "sucess"?

Comment: I know that returns true because within the header is so "www.mysite.com?result=$result" I forgot to show in the above example.

Comment: your email probably got into spam blockers... I had the very same problem and after checking out the logs I found out that mine was blocked for some unknown reason

Answer (score 2):

I would've commented but I don't have enough points.

This happened to me a couple weeks back. Just wanted to share that if you are using a general shared hosting plan, ask your web host to configure the domain to enable SPF.
(My package did not come with these settings as default - just check with your web host server).

Some of the domains hosted on my webhost server were receiving emails while others were not (the emails were bounced back to sender even if they were sent by Gmail). I could not figure out where the issue was until someone suggested that if you're on a shared hosting plan, check your records.

You can also find topics about it on cPanel's forums https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/email-can-send-not-receive.594419/

Just my 2 cents, hope it helps someone.

Comment: I agree, I was just to submit my answer about SPF but saw you already suggested it. SPF records + SMTP + making sure the IP is not blacklisted should clear the problem.